# How to figure out what and encoded string contains

Tags: encoding, decoding

I have a string that looks like this

> H4sIALYnhUsCA9VXW5aDIAz9zypcgiU8dDnTWtfQ5Q8kEgSR
>   ap05c+YnhxLyumBu2r/s2PUvO3nh+rCaw0oFob1Q+Z51HfjNZ1jexCSsLAYx
>   BGG6eATZGJYALIIzG9QOy4NeaPYAyyarKfQY7TgypTjGI3ogkxDahSTw7kX/
>   FQUHeIgxsoClQD1JGRKF7Jy4oXNeQFou5TvJzlkJoAUIMuGAOlePMTEGWQry
>   2liLCfHNJPEwuiU7jmzEhM6gnGawSO3ORMnqLQRsNgki7AV4jEI9xKRU65V6
>   q7UUZVetqsZQC13z3UzMXkkM24nlvs+B/EktqmsnC0dxelvLycTaN+QugYw/
>   DTJeeTD4iy/ZXQHZ/KuXjH/2kvFKYtfaBfXtaUtlVZCZiIxw5WPLLxkFQZ2D
>   mMBmUaQJYCKyyBlShVqMuHUFSzu5/UTY1sVMVpwzSnimpEFOz5G7nKSoheIt
>   yqjg+pxU54zE64jd3zzdrYmW6Ybic2mVvcjAUKfg0s0QMfAXDadyotuGxOdH
>   hwZIU4NPR2fqbApbVnirTRdFGc/cjr7KwhmV+m6GGbMnf+RetoNNGwiohW4D
>   AREJ1R0FAhqo7gDx4b18iBh/uWPeGkwc07mMmdtKbBe0WQy9PMpr6TpLZwhR
>   whmj8/8FjTEWsv8ckhimqgj9+2q0hfWH1WpFCXPYfX27mEMGupKe1QA+gkwd
>   PDVv/xO+AbHzd9RzDQAA

My initial guess was that this was a Base64encoded file of some sort. Any ideas on how I can figure out if/which type of file it is? It should contain MIME info I guess but how would I save it to a file without fragmenting it.

Comment: Why the encryption tags? Are you saying this is encrypted data and you want to work out what file it is? Any good cryptosystem will make that hard for you to prevent known plaintext (using known structures in certain file formats) attacks. Or are you trying to work out what file type it is? If so - how are you receiving this? Are they not sending the type for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's base64.  When you decode it, you get a gzipped file, which consists of a boatload of hex characters (literally, as ASCII 0xNN hex characters).  They're mostly in the A-Z,a-z range.

I'd paste it here, but from this, I suspect this is part of some exercise you're doing, so I think I'll leave it to you to figure out.

P.S. For edification, I determined the binary output was a gzipped file by using the unix `file` command, to identify the "magic" bytes, which showed that it was gzipped.  Use your `decode_base64` function or whatever it is, then dump the return value into a file and `gunzip` it.

Comment: I actully just cracked it... I missed on character in my decode... So I got a binary file now... Checking the mime type it was gzipped. Unzipped and got a file in hex format... So I think I got it soon.

Comment: Heh, it's pretty silly.  I finally unwrapped the last layer of the onion, and it ends up with 1 word, 10 characters long.  You will probably need to download a library to build and run the last bit.  Curious now what this is for, though, if it's not a big secret.  Is it a contest?

Comment: Just a little puzzle... My thought was that it might have been a hex encoded gif image or something... But when you say I will have to download a library it feels like it's a bit trickier than that.

Comment: Think I got it... Decoded the hex data and got a piece of code in what seem to be java. So now I just have to run that code and I think I'll be at the finishline :)

Comment: Aye, that's the ticket, mate :-)  Need an apache library, though, but I'm sure you've gotten it by now.